# What time format is this: 38793.20139

Tags: time, format

This data is from scientific tracking data. What is this date format:

38793.20139

I have looked through all of the stackoverflow datetime format entries I could find.

Comment: More information needed, such as what product (or even *type* of product) is producing the data (i.e., not just "it's scientific tracking data"). 38793 days ago from today is mid 1909 which would be a funny base date to use. Hours wouldn't be much better since that's only about four years or so.

Comment: My guess is it's a high-precision timestamp, where the floating point is sub-millisecond, but without knowing where it came from that's just an educated guess.

Comment: It looks kind of like how Excel stores dates and times. The integer part is days since the epoch and the fractional part is the fraction of the day. On a Mac, where the epoch is 1/1/1900 (or 1/1/1904, depending), that number corresponds to 3/17/2006 4:50 AM.

Comment: More sample data and the surrounding context may help. This is basically a reverse engineering task

Comment: It is a timestamp transmitted from tracking devices on live elephant seals. It could be anytime from 2002 to the present day.

Comment: I think it could be an excel timestamp. Unfortunately my version of excel only allows it to be translated into either date or time but not both. I am getting 3/18/10 from the date format and 4:50 am from the time format.

Comment: Could be serial date, as suggested by @blm: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

Comment: To see both date and time, format the cell, choose a type of Time, not date, then near the bottom of the format list, you'll see some formats with date and time.